# Prevent instantiation of a Moose abstract class

Tags: perl, abstract-class, moose

I am using Perl with Moose, and have to prevent instantiation of an abstract class.

The project is in a quite advanced stage - too late for `Moose::Role` or `MooseX::*`.

I am thinking about checking a package name against a class name in `BUILDARGS`, 
and calling `die` if there's a match.

Is there any problems with this approach?

```
package Foo::Abstract {

    use Moose;

    has 'test' => ( isa => 'Int', is => 'rw', default => '0' );

    around BUILDARGS => sub {
        die if $_[1] eq __PACKAGE__;
        $orig  = shift;
        $class = shift;
        $class->$orig( @_ );
    };

    no Moose;
}

package Foo::Concrete {

    use Moose;

    extends 'Foo::Abstract';

    no Moose;
}

use Test::More;
use Test::Exception;

dies_ok { Foo::Abstract->new() } "cannot instantiate. OK";

my $c;
lives_ok { $c = Foo::Concrete->new() } "instantiated Foo::Concrete. OK";

ok( 0 == $c->test );

done_testing();
```

Comment: Roles are the way to solve this.

Comment: I don't see how it can be "too late" for `Moose::Role`.

Comment: You _might_ be able to use the [weak_ref option](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Attributes.pod#Weak-references), but I agree with AKHolland and Borodin that you need to make time for Roles.

Comment: AKHolland, Borodin, interduoThanks. Moose::Role is the correct approach. But here is the real life situation. Adding `die if $_[1] eq  __PACKAGE__ ;` is one line modification in one package. Replacing `extends PackageName` with  `with PackageName` and  adding `requires method_name` to a number of packages, testing, debugging... Refactoring takes time.

Comment: The testing part should be calling `prove`, if you wrote proper tests. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several people have pointed out in comments you probably *should* be using a Role and making the change in every "subclass" to do composition. However you make a compelling argument for laziness (one change in one place during a refactor).

My suggestion would be "do both". Refactor the existing class you want to be abstract out into a role:

```
mv lib/Foo/Abstract.pm lib/Foo/Role/Interface.pm; 
perl -pie's/\bFoo::Abstract\b/Foo::Role::Interface/g' !$
```

Then in a new `Foo::Abstract` simply do:

```
package Foo::Abstract;
use Moose;
with qw(Foo::Role::Interface);
around BUILDARGS => sub { 
    $_[1] ne __PACKAGE__ ? shift->(@_) : die __PACKAGE__ . 'is ABSTRACT';
}
1;
```

This way you can slowly replace the `extends qw(Foo::Abstract)` over time with the more appropriate `with qw(Foo::Role::Interface)` but don't have to bite that cost all up front. You can even document that this is the plan in `Foo::Abstract` so that other developers who come along help with the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

How is it too late to use Roles?  Just replace:

```
use Moose;
```

with

```
use Moose::Role;
```

And in Foo::Concrete, replace

```
extends 'Foo::Abstract';
```

with

```
with 'Foo::Abstract';
```